# wiring homeline 70 amp panel fed by 2 12/2 wires how do I hook the wire up in the box , my intention is run a 2 pole 15 and a 2 pole 20

Tags: garage-door-opener

We recently bought home that was built in 1972 it had an old pole barn not in great condition, the power supply to the barn was 2 12/2 wires running off a 2 pole 40 amp breaker and going to a fuse box . I've torn that barn down and built a new one now I want to put in a home line 70 amp with the intention of a 2 pole 15amp for lights and a 2 pole 20amp for outlets and I need to know how to hook it up in the box ie: a hot to each lug and combine the neutrals or what any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to replace the paired 12/2 cables with a cable or wiring in conduit sufficient to a 40 amp supply breaker - that was a violation when installed and is a violation now.

Comment: A 40 amp breaker requires 8 gauge wire.  You will need to replace the cable going to the barn first.  Your new #8 goes to the main breaker or feeder bar and the neutral and grounds must be separate.  I'm sure a concise directive will be posted from those with more electrical knowledge. If you don't need 220 V only one hot lead is needed.

Comment: Larger aluminum wire/cable probably makes more sense than 8 AWG copper, actually.

Answer (score 2):

Previous owner violated code *multiple* times:

- All hots and neutral must be in the same cable - they were split (somehow) into 2 separate cables.
- Wire must be sized based on breaker, not anticipated usage. (There are certain exceptions with devices that include their own fuses or breakers, but that's not the case here). 12 AWG cable can't be used on a circuit larger than 20A.
- Based on the description, I suspect the cables are actually standard non-metallic cable and not cable rated for outdoor use, let alone direct burial.

The 40A breaker is fine for 2 x 20A circuits. In fact, it leaves you a bit of expansion room as the 40A is 240V and the individual circuits are 120V. But that cable **MUST** be replaced. Your options include:

- 8 AWG copper direct-burial rated cable
- 8 AWG copper individual wires in conduit
- 8 AWG aluminum direct-burial rated cable
- 8 AWG aluminum individual wires in conduit

See an [ampacity table](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) for the details. Ignore the 90 C columns. The ampacity varies depending on copper vs. aluminum and on cable vs. wire type. In general, at any given size, aluminum is a size up from copper. But at 40A (which is relatively low for a subpanel) everything ends up at 8 AWG. Large sizes of aluminum are *much* cheaper than large sizes of copper, and for feeders between panels that is just fine. Concerns about aluminum wiring are primarily with 15A and 20A branch circuits.

Larger wire is perfectly fine and allows for future expansion.

Depending on distance and other factors, conduit (either plastic or metal) with individual wires may make sense instead of cable. Cable is simpler and generally less expensive to install, but it must be direct-burial rated, not the standard indoor cabling. Wires in conduit have the advantage that you can put in smaller wires now and replace them later if you need more capacity.

The usual "separate building subpanel" rules apply:

- Two ground rods from the subpanel. That's in addition to the ground rods at the main panel.
- Disconnect required. That can be a "main breaker" on the subpanel, or 6 or fewer throws required to turn off everything in the subpanel.
- If you use a main breaker in the subpanel, it can be larger than the feed breaker and wire capacity.
- Subpanel must have neutrals and grounds separated and no neutral/ground bond.
- Feed is 4 wires - hot/hot/neutral/ground.
- Burial depth varies depending on cable vs. different conduit types.